# Ativando varias input com js

Tags: javascript

galera eu to tentando pegar varias name com mesmo nome no js e ativar elas mas sem sucesso segue o código;

```
function botao(){

    document.getElementsByName("titulo").disabled=false;
    document.getElementsByName("descriçao").disabled=false;
    document.getElementsByName("data").disabled=false;
    document.getElementsByName("submit").disabled=false;


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso é porque `getElementsByName` irá te retornar um array, mais especificamente um `NodeList`. Ao atribuir `false` para a propriedade `disabled` desse retorno, você só estará criando uma propriedade chamada `disabled` no array, mas você deveria estar atribuindo esse valor para os itens dentro do array, não para o array em si.

Note que no jQuery é possível utilizar um método para atribuir propriedades a todos os resultado da sua query, talvez seja isto que esteja causando confusão, mas em JavaScript puro você precisa percorrer o array e atribuir o valor para cada item manualmente:

```
function botao() {

    for (var titulo    of document.getElementsByName("titulo"))    titulo.disabled    = false;
    for (var descricao of document.getElementsByName("descriçao")) descricao.disabled = false;
    for (var data      of document.getElementsByName("data"))      data.disabled      = false;
    for (var submit    of document.getElementsByName("submit"))    submit.disabled    = false;

}
```

Comment: Uma alternativa interessante seria usar um só `for` e capturar todos os elementos com `querySelectorAll`.